# Spring Security ( OAuth2-server ) doesn't redirect to given url and occur 401 error

Tags: spring-boot, spring-security, oauth-2.0, spring-oauth2

I made a OAuth2 server with spring boot 3.x + spring-security-oauht2-authorization-server-1.22

```
    public SecurityConfiguration( AuthService authService ) {
        this.authService = authService;
    }

    @Bean
    @Order( 1 )
    public SecurityFilterChain authorizationServerSecurityFilterChain( HttpSecurity http)
            throws Exception {


        OAuth2AuthorizationServerConfiguration.applyDefaultSecurity(http);
        http.getConfigurer( OAuth2AuthorizationServerConfigurer.class)
                .oidc( Customizer.withDefaults() )
                ;
////                .authorizationEndpoint( Customizer.withDefaults() )
////                .tokenGenerator(
////                        new OAuth2TokenGenerator< OAuth2Token >() {
////                            @Override
////                            public OAuth2Token generate( OAuth2TokenContext context ) {
////
////                                Instant now = Instant.now();
////
////                                long accessLive = context.getRegisteredClient().getTokenSettings().getAccessTokenTimeToLive().toSeconds();
////                                long refreshLive = context.getRegisteredClient().getTokenSettings().getRefreshTokenTimeToLive().toSeconds();
////
////                                if( context.getTokenType() == OAuth2TokenType.ACCESS_TOKEN )
////                                    return new OAuth2AccessToken( OAuth2AccessToken.TokenType.BEARER, UUID.randomUUID().toString(),now, now.plusSeconds( accessLive ));
////                                else if( context.getTokenType() == OAuth2TokenType.REFRESH_TOKEN)
////                                    return new OAuth2RefreshToken( UUID.randomUUID().toString(), now, now.plusSeconds( refreshLive ) );
////                                else {
////
////                                    JwtEncoder jwtEncoder = new NimbusJwtEncoder(jwkSource());
////                                    JwtGenerator jwtGenerator = new JwtGenerator(jwtEncoder);
////
////                                    return jwtGenerator.generate( context );
////                                }
////
////                            }
////
////                        }
////                )
////                .authorizationEndpoint( a -> a.authorizationResponseHandler( new AuthenticationSuccessHandler() {
////                    @Override
////                    public void onAuthenticationSuccess( HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, Authentication authentication ) throws IOException, ServletException {
////                        System.out.println("ddddd");
////                    }
////                } ) )
//      ;
//
////
//      http.exceptionHandling(exceptions -> exceptions
//              .defaultAuthenticationEntryPointFor(
//                      new LoginUrlAuthenticationEntryPoint( "/login" ),
//                      new MediaTypeRequestMatcher( MediaType.TEXT_HTML)
//              ));

        return http.build();
    }
    @Bean
    @Order(2)
    public SecurityFilterChain defaultSecurityFilterChain(HttpSecurity http)
            throws Exception {
        http
                .authorizeHttpRequests( requests -> requests.anyRequest().permitAll())
                .csrf( httpSecurityCsrfConfigurer -> httpSecurityCsrfConfigurer.disable())
                .cors( httpSecurityCorsConfigurer -> httpSecurityCorsConfigurer.disable() )
                // Form login handles the redirect to the login page from the
                // authorization server filter chain
                .formLogin( Customizer.withDefaults() );
        ;

        return http.build();
    }


    @Bean
    public UserDetailsService userDetailsService() {

        UserDetails userDetails = User.withDefaultPasswordEncoder()
                .username( "user" )
                .password( "user" )
                .roles( "USER" )
                .build();

        return new InMemoryUserDetailsManager( userDetails );
    }



//  @Bean AuthorizationFilter authorizationFilter( ){
//
//      return new AuthorizationFilter( new AuthorizationManager< HttpServletRequest >() {
//          @Override
//          public AuthorizationDecision check( Supplier< Authentication > authentication, HttpServletRequest object ) {
//
//              System.out.println("dhdhiahsdfoihasdofhjadsofasdfasdfasdfasdfasdfasdfasdf");
//              return new AuthorizationDecision( true );
//          }
//      } );
//  }
    @Bean
    public RegisteredClientRepository registeredClientRepository() {
        RegisteredClient oidcClient = RegisteredClient.withId( UUID.randomUUID().toString())
                .clientId("client")
                .clientSecret("{noop}secret")
                .scope( OidcScopes.OPENID )
                .scope( OidcScopes.PROFILE )
//              .clientAuthenticationMethod( ClientAuthenticationMethod.CLIENT_SECRET_JWT )
                .clientAuthenticationMethod( ClientAuthenticationMethod.CLIENT_SECRET_POST )

                .clientAuthenticationMethod( ClientAuthenticationMethod.NONE )
                .authorizationGrantType( AuthorizationGrantType.AUTHORIZATION_CODE)
                .authorizationGrantType(AuthorizationGrantType.REFRESH_TOKEN)
//              .redirectUri( "http://localhost:8000/login" )
                .redirectUri( UI_LOCAL_URL )
//              .postLogoutRedirectUri("http://localhost:8002/")
//              .tokenSettings( TokenSettings.builder()
//                      .accessTokenTimeToLive( Duration.ofSeconds( 3600 ) )
//                      .refreshTokenTimeToLive( Duration.ofDays( 1 ) )
//                      .build() )
//              .clientSettings( ClientSettings.builder()
//                      .requireAuthorizationConsent(true)
//                      .build())
                .build();

        return new InMemoryRegisteredClientRepository(oidcClient);
    }

    @Bean
    public JWKSource< SecurityContext > jwkSource() {
        KeyPair keyPair = generateRsaKey();
        RSAPublicKey publicKey = (RSAPublicKey) keyPair.getPublic();
        RSAPrivateKey privateKey = (RSAPrivateKey) keyPair.getPrivate();
        RSAKey rsaKey = new RSAKey.Builder(publicKey)
                .privateKey(privateKey)
                .keyID(UUID.randomUUID().toString())
                .build();
        JWKSet jwkSet = new JWKSet(rsaKey);
        return new ImmutableJWKSet<>(jwkSet);
    }

    private static KeyPair generateRsaKey() {
        KeyPair keyPair;
        try {
            KeyPairGenerator keyPairGenerator = KeyPairGenerator.getInstance("RSA");
            keyPairGenerator.initialize(2048);
            keyPair = keyPairGenerator.generateKeyPair();
        }
        catch (Exception ex) {
            throw new IllegalStateException(ex);
        }
        return keyPair;
    }

    @Bean
    public JwtDecoder jwtDecoder( JWKSource< SecurityContext > jwkSource) {
        return OAuth2AuthorizationServerConfiguration.jwtDecoder(jwkSource);
    }

    @Bean
    public AuthorizationServerSettings authorizationServerSettings() {
        return AuthorizationServerSettings.builder().build();
    }
```

And then I called http://localhost:8002/oauth2/authorize?response_type=code&client_id=client&scpoe=openid&redirect_uri=http://localhost:3000/login.

I expected my auth server redirect to given url. but it doesn't work.
they give 401 error.

So I debug my code.

and when authorization filter works, authorization filter made a authorization decision (isGranted =false).

I think this made a 401 error.
but I didn't have idea...

please let me know how to fix it...!

and here is debug log

```
[2024-03-18 11:32:06.079][http-nio-8002-exec-1] DEBUG [org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.defaultWithAnonymous:119] - Set SecurityContextHolder to anonymous SecurityContext
[2024-03-18 11:32:06.087][http-nio-8002-exec-1] DEBUG [org.springframework.security.web.savedrequest.HttpSessionRequestCache.saveRequest:80] - Saved request http://localhost:8002/oauth2/authorize?response_type=code&client_id=client&scpoe=openid&redirect_uri=http://localhost:3000/login&continue to session
```